# How can I bind a ListView Item with data outside from model in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to bind a list view item with a data that is not in model. I have the model like this-

```
public class Recording
{
        public string ArtistName { get; set; }
        public string CompositionName { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDateTime { get; set; }
}
public ObservableCollection<Recording> Recordings = new ObservableCollection<Recording>();
public Visibility ButtonVisibility = Visibilty.Collasped;
```

And the code that I have tried is like below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Recordings}"
HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
            <Button Content="OK" Visibility="{Binding ButtonVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName, Mode=OneWay }"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here, ButtonVisibility binding is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple way to achieve it without additional C# code is ...

1. Put a dummy UI element outside the DataTemplate (=a Button in ListView.Resources in this example) and let it bind ButtonVisibility.
2. In the DataTemplate, bind its Visibility by specifying binding-source with ElementName.

.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Recordings}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="RelayButtonVisibility" Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.ButtonVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Recording">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Content="OK" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=RelayButtonVisibility}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName, Mode=OneWay }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In case you don't like using the extra UIElement, define your own MyVisibility DependencyProperty or something in the Page class. And bind it similarly.